# Attribute routing not hitting the action methods inside controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing, attributerouting

I'm using attribute routing in my MVC5 application and it is working fine. When I tried to create an area and placed attribute routing on the controller inside it, it returns 404.

I know, to enable attribute routing inside Area, I have to use `[RouteArea("Area Name Here")]` and also have to add `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` inside my RouteConfig class. I did all this and designed my controller like this:

```
[RouteArea("Client")]
[RoutePrefix("Client")]
public class ClientController : Controller
{
    #region Properties
    private readonly string apiUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiUrl"];
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public ClientController()
    {

    }
    #endregion

    #region Action Methods
    [HttpGet, Route("create")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       --logic here
    }
    #endregion
 }
```

When i run the application using the route: `http://localhost:26189/Client/create`, I'm able to hit the constructor but not the Index method. Interestingly, if i remove the attribute `[HttpGet, Route("create")]` and try this route `http://localhost:26189/Client/Index` it will hit the Index method.

I'm going through these links but not found the exact fix:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/#route-areas

Comment: I guess you also need ActionName attribute like `[ActionName("create")]` for index action.

Comment: @Amit - I have tried to add thi attribute but no luck :(

Comment: Is there routing definition elsewhere which is overriding yours?

Comment: what does the routearea do?, seems like the call would become "/Client/Client/create"?

Answer (score 0):

You likely have ordering problems in your startup path. Make sure things are called in this order:

1. `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();`
2. `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`
3. Any convention-based routes

Comment: Tried it but still not able to fix the issue :(